# spring boot auto configuration. unexpected behaviour

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

I am trying to use spring boot auto configuration feature and got an issue.
I created a github repo to be able to reproduce easily the "issue":

```
git clone https://github.com/clembo590/issues.git --branch spring_boot_auto_configuration
```

just run `mvn clean install` and you will get all the logs I am refering to in my description.

I have "enabled" the `debug=true` spring boot property to see which 'autoconfiguration' is activated or not (and if it is not active why it is not active).

I also have added some logs to "log all the beans that have been added to the spring boot context".

Here is my autoConfiguration class.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = MyClass.class)
@ConditionalOnBean(ObjectMapper.class)
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CleaningAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Fake fake(){
        return new Fake();
    }

    private static class Fake{

    }

}
```

The very first weird thing is this log:

```
   CleaningAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'jacksonObjectMapper' (OnBeanCondition)
```

First question:
Why is @ConditionalOnBean BOTH matching and Not matching ? (my expectation about such a condition is that it should either match or not match... but not both... see question 5)

Now if we look at the logs it seems that `CleaningAutoConfiguration` is in the `Negative matches:` section.

Second question:
why is `CleaningAutoConfiguration` itself registered as a bean ? (I was expecting it would not as it is in the `Negative matches` section).

Third question:
Why is `fake` still registered as a bean (I was expecting that `fake` would not be registered, and not even instanciated...)

Fourth question:
why is `MyClass` not registered as a bean ?

Now if you remove the `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = MyClass.class)` then all those questions go away as `CleaningAutoConfiguration` goes into `Positive matches` section, but one new is created:

fifth question:
Why removing the @ComponentScan brings `CleaningAutoConfiguration` into `Positive matches` section ? (maybe question 5 is somehow connected to question 1 .... ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is the use of `@ComponentScan` on an auto-configuration class which is [not supported](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.3/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-auto-configuration.locating-auto-configuration-candidates):

> Furthermore, auto-configuration classes should not enable component scanning to find additional components. Specific `@Import`s should be used instead.

To answer your specific questions:

> Why is `@ConditionalOnBean` BOTH matching and not matching

It's first evaluated as part of considering the unsupported `@ComponentScan` annotation. At this time, the `ObjectMapper` bean has not been defined so it does not match. It's subsequently evaluated after the `ObjectMapper` bean has been defined at which point it matches.

> why is CleaningAutoConfiguration itself registered as a bean ? (I was expecting it would not as it is in the Negative matches section).

The report has mislead you here due to the positive and negative match. `CleaningAutoConfiguration` is a bean due to the positive match.

> Why is fake still registered as a bean (I was expecting that fake would not be registered, and not even instanciated...)

The report has misled you again. The conditions on `CleaningAutoConfiguration` have been matched so its `Fake` bean has been defined.

> why is `MyClass` not registered as a bean

The conditions on `CleaningAutoConfiguration` did not match when the `@ComponentScan` annotation was being considered so component scanning of `MyClass`'s package was not enabled.

> Why removing the `@ComponentScan` brings `CleaningAutoConfiguration` into Positive matches section

It prevents the conditions on `CleaningAutoConfiguration` being evaluated prematurely at a time when the `ObjectMapper` bean has not yet been defined. When they are eventually evaluated at the expected time, the `ObjectMapper` bean is present and the conditions match.

Comment: This is a great answer thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.